# How are primitive data types made in C#?

Tags: c#, primitive-types

How do `System.float`, `System.int` and other primitives types work? I never understood how it was possible to make primitives structs and I wonder if I could make my own numeric type.

Comment: They're build into the language, at the IL level.

Comment: @john: It's important to note that those are two different things though: `decimal` is built into the C# language, but *isn't* built into IL. That's what makes this question interesting IMO.

Comment: The processor designer created them.  Intel.  That's what makes them "primitive", the hardware directly manipulates these values at sub-nanosecond speeds.  Consider looking at the code for [BigInteger](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,035eb7acfa6585a0) to see how to create your own numeric type.  One hangup you'll run into is that you can't define your own literal values without changing the compiler.

Comment: [History of Floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#History). SPOILER: it was not Intel. What is relevant today is that they are standard under [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) and every major PC CPU manufacturer (including, but not limited to Intel) have support for them in the design of their chips.

Comment: I have the feeling this question is by far too broad and thus attracts many differing answers all handling a specific layer of abstraction. Whilst some talk about CLI/LI, others talk about chip-based features. Of course they are all right, but we don´t know at which layer OP works.

Comment: When two bytes love each other very very much...

Comment: @Theraot. I bet if you go back far enough, it all ties in to the width of a horse-drawn cart in ancient Rome.

Comment: Jon's answer is of course correct. I would note that the C# specification only uses the term "primitive type" once, and does not define it, so it is not 100% clear what exactly counts as a "primitive" type. Also, it sounds like you're asking a bit of an "XY" problem here. **What numeric type do you want to make?** Maybe you should be asking your question about that.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid they "fork" and create a child process

Comment: @Mixxiphoid, I'm sorry, that's neither 'true' nor 'false'...

Comment: The compiler is hard-wired to know about them. Interestingly, once you have a compiler that accepts them, you can use it to compile a compiler that itself uses them. See re [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)) and the thrilling/horrifying [Turing Award lecture by Dennis Ritchie](http://vxer.org/lib/pdf/Reflections%20on%20Trusting%20Trust.pdf) (inventor of C).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about a C# compiler which targets the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI), as almost everything does, it basically uses the primitive types exposed by the CLI.

There are effectively three levels of support to consider:

- Genuine primitives, with their own representation and instructions in IL
- Numeric types that the C# compiler has special knowledge of, but which aren't part of the the CLI - basically, `System.Decimal`. This is *also* part of the Common Type System (CTS) which means that if you create a `const decimal` in C#, you can still consume it in VB, for example. But there's still no direct *IL* support.
- Other numeric types, such as `BigInteger` - you can write your own ones of these.

The middle ground of the second bullet allows C# to have decimal literals and decimal constants, neither of which are possible for the third bullet. For example, `BigInteger` doesn't have language support, so you can't write:

```
// This isn't valid
BigInteger bigInteger = 123456789012345678901234567890;
```

You'd have to parse a string representation instead. Likewise you can't have a `const BigInteger`.

(In theory it would be possible to have a type with support in C# but not in the CTS. I don't know of any such types.)

Comment: Although I am not the question asker, I hadn't thought about Decimal, so thank you for this informative answer.

Comment: This link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence-and-language-independent-components says "The .NET Framework common type system includes a number of built-in types that are supported directly by the common language runtime and are specially encoded in an assembly's metadata", and in the following table it lists System.Decimal. How so? Or it's not the same as being part of CLI?

Comment: @Evk: Being part of the CTS isn't quite the same as being part of the CLI. I'll put a bit more info in the answer.

Comment: Do unsigned types fall into the same bucket as `decimal`?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: No, they're in the CLI as well.

Answer (score 7):

Primitive types like `int` and `float` are supported directly by the processor, and the .net platform and languages have similar built-in support for them. So there are no way you could create your own primitives at the language level.